# How to update StatusStrip in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

I am trying to update the status strip in my [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application, but nothing is being displayed. Here is my code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lines = Regex.Split(textBox1.Text.Trim(), "\r\n");
    lineCount = lines.Count();
    statusStrip1.Text = "Lines: " + lineCount;
    statusStrip1.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[image]

You will need to add a `ToolStripStatusLabel` to the `StatusStrip`.

Then set the text of the label instead (you need to do a `statusstrip.Refresh` as there is no refresh on the status-label).

The `Text` property on the `StatusStrip` comes from the StatusStrip inherits `ToolStrip` (which in turn inherits `Control`), but has no visual effect due to the nature of ToolStrips. It can be a bit confusing.

Example:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    lines = Regex.Split(textBox1.Text.Trim(), "\r\n");
    lineCount = lines.Count();

    //this label is added in visual editor using the default name
    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = string.Format("Lines: {0}", lineCount);
    StatusStrip1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Update ***StatusStrip*** in `multi-threading` requires **InvokeRequired** or _TPL Tasks_, *IMHO*.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, where I see a `StatusStrip` control but apparently without `ToolStripStatusLabel` item within the parent control. Not even the initial text for the `ToolStripStatusLabel` item (e.g., "Ready") was displayed. The label item's `Spring` was set to `true` and `TextAlign` to `TopLeft`.

The problem was resolved by setting the StatusStrip control's `LayoutStyle` to `Flow` and the `ToolStripStatusLabel` item's `Overflow` to `Never`. Apparently the label item was hidden when the parent control's layout style was set to `Table`.